# Compile errors in Visual Basic 6.0 in a one-line tutorial program

Tags: vb6

I've just installed MS Visual Basic 6.0 on my computer, and I'm trying to figure out what it's about. I've found [this tutorial](http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson2.html). Example 2.1.1 is

```
 Private Sub Form_Load ( )

 Form1.show

 Print “Welcome to Visual Basic tutorial”

 End Sub
```

I've pasted this where they say I should, pressed F5, and I'm getting error messages.

When I first press F5, I get this:

[image]

I click OK and press F5 again. Then I get a different message:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Have you considered learning VB 2012 instead? It's free, and it's much better. I would not recommend learning VB6 unless you have a good reason to learn it, e.g. existing code to support.

Comment: @MarkJ Thank you for the comment. Yes, I'm not going to learn VB6 in detail. But from experience in other fields (mathematics and physics) I know that going through stuff chronologically gives me better understanding. So I prefer to learn a bit about VB6 first, and then I'll start with the .NET versions.

Comment: @ymar Following your analogy, learning "American History" will not make you any better at Mathematics.  Similarly, learning VB6 will not make you any better at learning VB 2012.

Comment: @GMastros Hi. I don't think that was my analogy. It's just that when I learn a new theory in maths, I find it useful to know how it came about (in particular what was tried earlier and got abandoned or changed). It gives me a better understanding because it explains why some things are this way and not any other way.

Comment: @ymar You might as well start learning to program in assembly if that's the way you look at programming. You'll gain no particular insight by starting at a lower version, and you could even harm your learning as the modern way of doing things has moved on.

Comment: @abizern I would actually love to try writing something in assembly. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a copy-past problem:

```
Print “Welcome to Visual Basic tutorial”
```

SHould be:

```
Print "Welcome to Visual Basic tutorial"
```

(normal double quotes)

Comment: Thanks! I'd never have noticed that!